# Image not showing up on page? using .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Image isn't showing up in the main body of my page. All that's showing is an empty *imagebox*. And the console shows an error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

All my images are in a folder called *ProductImages*, So i think I'm not using the correct source for the image but still can't get it working.

```
   $("#mainBody").append("<img src =" + imageFilename + ">");
```

Comment: in `src` you have to give correct image path. it seems that `imageFilename`  having only image name not the path of that image

Comment: what is value in imageFilename ??

Answer (score 0):

When setting an image `src`, you need to specify a valid path to the image resource.

If the images are under a directory called `ProductImages` which is under the root directory of your website, Try this:

```
$("#mainBody").append("<img src ="'/ProductImages/" + imageFilename + "'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the image in project folder & show from that path.